# Agregar href a un boton

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Tengo este boton y quiero agregarle un a href, pero como la pagina esta hecha con un constructor "Elementor" de wordpress pero no puedo cambiarlo directamente en el codigo así que he tratado con funciones como esta que he encontrado en otros foros pero no me sirve.

```
var a = document.getElementById('yourlinkId'); 
a.href = "somelink url"
```

Alguna forma de como hacerlo?
Gracias

[image: e]

Comment: aclaro que cambie los nombres en la funcion

Comment: Hola @Daniel Salinas disculpa pero no queda muy clara tu pregunta. ¿Quieres agregar el href al botón y hacer que al dar click este funcione como un link? ¿o quieres solamente agregar el href al botón para usarlo luego en alguna función?

Comment: si que al dar click funcione como link

Comment: si seleccionas el botón en elementor hay una pestaña avanzado, ahí podes agregarle un id

Answer (score 1):

Este sería un HTML de ejemplo:

```
<input type="button" value="Buscador" class="buscador" id="mibuscador"/>
```

Este sería el JQuery:

```
    $('.buscador').click(function () {
        window.open = 'https://www.google.com';
    });
```

o bien:

```
    $('#mibuscador').click(function () {
        window.open = 'https://www.google.com';
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Bueno por lo que entiendo quieres hacer elementos clickeables

Para un solo elemento:

```
document.getElementById('myBtn').addEventListener('click', () => {
 window.open('tu url')
});
```

Para múltiples elementos:

```
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".MyClassName");
buttons.forEach((button) => {
    button.addEventListener("click", () =>  window.open('tu url'));
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo te recomiendo que en vez de un botón utilices un href directamente y le des estilo con css, es mucho más práctico y aparte dejas el código más limpio y entendible.
Para que tenga aspecto de botón deberías darle un border, bg y un border radius, aparte si quieres que te quede más pulido y una apariencia de botón total también podrías hacer un :hover con un transition con eso puedes hacer que se haga más grande o cambiar el border radius, cambiarle el bg o incluso puedes buscar algún estilo por Internet ya que los hay muy bonitos.